# SQLAlchemy ORM Update for HSTORE fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, hstore

I have a problem when I try to update hstore field. I have the following translation hybrid and database model.

```
translation_hybrid = TranslationHybrid(
    current_locale='en',
    default_locale='de'
)
```

```
class Book:
    __tablename__ = "Book"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    title_translations = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE), nullable=False)

    title = translation_hybrid(title_translations)
```

I want to update title with the current locale using a single orm query. When I try the following query

```
query(Book).filter(Book.id == id).update({"title": "new_title"})
```

ORM converts this to the following sql:

```
UPDATE "Book" SET coalesce(title_translations -> 'en', title_translations -> 'de') = "new_title" WHERE "Book".id = id
```

And this sql gives the syntax error. What is the best way to update it without fetching the model first and assigning the value to the field?

Answer (score 2):

We got this to run eventually, documenting here for the benefit of others that might run into this issue; Note that we're using the new `select` methodology and `async`.

As you already suggested, we solved this by assigning the updated values directly to the record object. We're basically implementing [this solution from the SQLAlchemy docu](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#updating-orm-objects):

```
    updated_record: models.Country = None  # type: ignore
    try:
        # fetch current data from database and lock for update
        record = await session.execute(
            select(models.Country)
            .filter_by(id=str(country_id))
            .with_for_update(nowait=True)
        )
        updated_record = record.scalar_one()
        logger.debug(
            "update() - fetched current data from database",
            record=record,
            updated_record=vars(updated_record),
        )

        # merge country_dict (which holds the data to be updated) with the data in the DB
        for key, value in country_dict.items():
            setattr(updated_record, key, value)
        logger.debug(
            "update() - merged new data into record",
            updated_record=vars(updated_record),
        )

        # flush data to database
        await session.flush()

        # refresh updated_record and commit
        await session.refresh(updated_record)
        await session.commit()

    except Exception as e:  # noqa: PIE786
        logger.error("update() - an error occurred", error=str(e))
        await session.rollback()
        raise ValueError("Record can not be updated.")

    return updated_record
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved a similar instance of the problem using the [bulk update query variant](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-bulk-update-by-primary-key).

In this case a PoC solution would look like this:

```py
session.execute(update(Book), [{"id": id, "title": title}])
session.commit()
```

I am not sure why this does not trigger the `coalesce()` issue but it seems to be working. We should probably open an issue in SQLAlchemy as I don't have the time right now to debug it to its root cause.

**UPDATE**
I think that the original issue actually originates in `sqlalchemy-util` as the coalesce seems to arise from the `expr_factory` of the hybrid property [here](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/blob/0b1bc8728c0e01b73aa06b85e85ab4cbda6a9224/sqlalchemy_utils/i18n.py#L109).

Comment: Yes, it is originated in `sqlalchemy-util`. I think I spotted the problem and may have the solution for this. So I will test it and create a PR for this to `sqlalchemy-util` repo if it solves the issue. I will update here.

Comment: Nice, I think I also have a PoC that slightly modifies the compiler for the locale expression cast that does a different thing when in an update statement by checking the `compiler.isupdate` flag. This requires moving the coalesce function in there as well. I haven't gotten it to work completely yet, though. Let me know when you have a PR, I'm happy to check it out.